# Firebase Realtime Database Data Loads After Component is Rendered

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this React component here:

```
import Navbar from "../../nav/Navbar";
import './Cold.css';

// API Calls
import { getCold } from '../../api/cold/get'

function ColdWork (){

    const [coldWorkItem, setColdWork] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        getColdWork().then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);

    const getColdWork = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const coldWork = await getCold();
        console.log('Cold Work: ', coldWork);
        setColdWork(coldWork);
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Cold Work Items: ', coldWorkItem);
        // setLoading(false);
    }, [coldWorkItem]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="cold-container">

                {loading ? (
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                ) : (
                    <div className="cc-inner">
                    {coldWorkItem.length > 0 ? (
                        coldWorkItem.map((item, index) => (
                            <div key={index} className="cc-item">
                                <h3>{item.associated_timecard_key}</h3>
                                <p>{item.cold_key}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <p>No Cold Work Items</p>
                    )}
                </div>
                )}



            </div>
            <h1>Cold Work</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ColdWork;
```

The getCold() function looks like this:

```
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';


export const getCold = async () => {
    const dbReference = getDatabase();
    const coldRef = ref(dbReference, 'all_cold');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        onValue(coldRef, (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            resolve(data);
        }, (error) => {
            reject(error);
        })
    })
}
```

I know this is an asynchronous process and the data arrives shortly after this page loads. I am still trying to get a handle on the hooks in React, including useEffect. I can see in my browser console that the data is loading correctly. It's coming in. That part is fine. However I will get one of two problems with the current code:

1. Without all the extra logic, I get errors stating coldWorkItem cannot be mapped over or iterated.
2. With the extra conditional checks, the component still skips right to `<p>No Cold Work Items</p>`

Is there anything I can do to add a slight delay to when this component finally renders? Should I be using some other means to fetch the data from realtime database? If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.